# Issues about crawling using selenium on mac os

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, geckodriver

I am beginning to learn web crawling using selenium. I have downloaded selenium for firefox and the geckodriver. So far I'm just trying to open up google, but I got a whole bunch of errors. Does anyone know what could have gone wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: p.s. I screenshotted the error messages because I didn't know how to keep the format and color...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine

You probably need to enter your driver's path correctly and make sure your driver version is the same as your browser and make sure the driver matches your operating system and its type.

Put your driver in another folder, for example in \home\Download Then enter your driver path in your script